# PHP isn't recognizing data posted by ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm sending an ajax call to my PHP script as follows:

```
function load(){
    var request = {};
    request['action'] = 'load';
    request['file'] = 'lorem_ipsum.txt';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: cgi_file,
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'application/html',
        success:function(response){
            console.log("received " + response);
        }
    });
}
```

and my PHP script is as follows:

```
$content_dir = '/static/content/';

$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action){
    case 'load':
        $file = $_POST['filename'];
        echo file_get_contents($content_dir . $file);
        exit();
}
```

The PHP is responding with the following failure:

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in /var/www/river/api.php on line 5
```

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ditch `processData: false` and `contentType: 'application/html'` and it should work

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: cgi_file,
    data: request,
    dataType: 'html',
    success:function(response){
        console.log("received " + response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well you need "Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which is default. And you are not sending DOMDocument (or other unprocessed data to the server) so you need processData: true which is also default.  See [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

Just leave `data` as it is:

```
data: request,
```

You don't need to stringify it.

Also, your `file` parameter allows an attacker to read arbitrary files from your filesystem. Sanitize it.

Comment: Didn't change anything. :/

Comment: @RiverTam: Print out the `$_POST` variable. What does it look like?

Comment: Well, $_POST itself just says "Array". I iterated over it using "foreach ($_POST as $i){echo $i;}" and it appeared completely empty.

Comment: Additionally, how would I go about sanitizing the file parameter?

Comment: @RiverTam: A good place to start is stripping out all `/`s. I don't work with PHP, but this looks useful as well: https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/

Answer (score 0):

A few things wrong here, firstly the `contentType` property is for the data you are sending to the server, secondly dataType should be set to `text` as that is what you are recieveing from the server. If you want to receive the data in the `$_POST` array your javascript should look like this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: cgi_file,
    data: {
        action: "load",
        file: "lorem_ipsum.txt";
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    success:function(response){
        console.log("received " + response);
    }
});
```

Jquery will send your data as a standard post to your server side code.